# How to get the particular product quantity in orders in Woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on my WooCommerce project and I am sending mail to the customer and in that I am sending the particular product quantity. So, I am not able to get that particular product quantity from the order.

**This is code:**

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$item_quantity=0;
$targeted_id = 14988;
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
$item_quantity += $item->get_quantity();
}
```

I want to get the '14988' product quantity from the orders. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: @TomJNowell, WooCommerce and plugins are part of WordPress and you should understand this. if these questions are not asked here then where we can ask this questions?

Comment: there are lots of places to ask this question, such as WooCommerce support, the WooCommerce support forums, the WooCommerce FB group, the Adv WP Facebook group, to name a few. WooCommerce is a 3rd party product produced by Automattic, we have a longstanding rule that 3rd party themes/plugins/products are off-topic. WooCommerce's popularity doesn't mean it can bypass those rules. If you think it should, you should ask on the meta stack where the rules and scope of this stack are discussed and things like this are decided as a community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the foreach you need to check each item for its product id and compare it to the targeted id

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

$item_quantity = 0;
$targeted_id = 14988;

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    // check if current item (product) id is equal to targeted id
    if ($item->get_product_id() == $targeted_id) {
        $item_quantity += $item->get_quantity();
        // once the correct cart item is found we no longer need to loop all other products so we break out of the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay but why you are adding this: $item_quantity += $item->get_quantity();

Comment: It can be $item_quantity = $item->get_quantity(); because we get the particular product quantity.

Comment: So, what do you think about this. Please respond and I will mark this answer. Thank you.

Comment: True. If you only need the one than += can be replaced with =. You can leave it if in the future you would like the quantity of two products. Its up to you =]. I tried to keep your original code the same as in the question, the += was already in the question =]

Comment: Yes, It is only one product that's why we are matching the product id and getting the quantity. Thank you for the answer.